# conversion from string constant to char*

Tags: c++, arduino

I am new to programming and am working on a project for a class. I am trying to use a keypad to enter a password. I cant figure out the "conversion from string constant to char* error I keep getting.

This is my code:

```
Password password = Password( "1234" );

const byte ROWS = 4; //Four rows
const byte COLS = 4; //Four columns

char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
{ '1','2','3','A'},
{'4','5','6','B'},
{'7','8','9','C'},
{'*','0','#','D'}};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {
46, 47, 48, 49};  //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {
50, 51, 52, 53};  //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad

//Create the Keypad
Keypad keypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);
```

any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You should at least indicate which line generates that error. Mind-reading is hard. Probably you wrote a function whose prototype says `char*` instead of `const char *`

Comment: I'm *guessing*, since you're not showing us, that the `Password` constructor takes a `char*`, but you're giving it a `const char*`. So add `const` to the constructor's argument, or better yet; make it `std::string`.

Comment: Try to paste code that contains at least the declarations of the things you use.

Comment: I'm not trying to make anyone "mind-read" I'm just looking for help. I am trying to learn and understand all of this. I apologize for not making this clear. But thank you for the quick responses.

Comment: When I try to compile it, it does not tell me which line is generating the error.

Comment: @M.White Could you show us the *exact* output of the compilation? (I don't believe that it doesn't contain the line number.) BTW, which compiler are you using?

Comment: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

 Password password = Password( "1234" );

Comment: @M.White Surely that's not all of it? Are you using an IDE? Are you looking at the compilation log or just a summary? Anyway, it looks like the problem is with the constructor. Show us `Password`'s declaration.

Comment: C:\Users\mwhit_000\Desktop\Capstone\Security_System\Security_System2\Security_System2.ino:27:38: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

 Password password = Password( "1234" );

                                      ^


Sketch uses 11,850 bytes (4%) of program storage space. Maximum is 253,952 bytes.
Global variables use 1,022 bytes (12%) of dynamic memory, leaving 7,170 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 8,192 bytes.
     That is everything that comes up at the bottom after I compile. And I apologize, I'm using the Arduino 1.6.7 compiler

Comment: @M.White So it did include the line number (27). Now show us the declaration of the `Password` class. (And don't post it in a comment; [edit] the question.)

Comment: The first line in the code I provided is actually line 27 in my code. I'm guessing there is something wrong with that line? If I could figure out how to give you all my code I would.

Comment: @M.White I've already given it my best guess. You should *at least* show us the declaration of the constructor.

Comment: @Biffen Do you have a different way to communicate so that maybe I can send you my entire code?

Comment: @M.White No. And I doubt I have to see *all* of it. Just [edit] the question to include `Password`'s constructor. It shouldn't be more than a handful of lines. (In fact, I think I know *exactly* what it looks like.)

Comment: Here's the answer: in C++, string constants have the type `const char [N]`, where `N` is the number of characters in the string plus one for the null terminator. So `"hi"` has the type `const char[3]`. Given an array `T[N]`, you can implicitly convert it to a pointer `T*`, which will point to the first element (equivalent to `&arr[0]`). However, if `T` is `const`, such as `const char`, you cannot just convert to `char*`  because you'd be dropping `const`; you need to convert it to `const char*`.  You *used* to be able to do this in C++ for historical reasons, but it has been fixed.

Comment: But use `std::string` instead of C-style arrays or pointers for strings.

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-answer, but comments have so-far been unable to explain what's going on to OP, so here's a longer, more detailed shot at it.

The actual output looks something like this

```
C:\Users\mwhit_000\Desktop\Capstone\Security_System\Security_System2\Security_Sy‌​stem2.ino:27:38: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings] 
Password password = Password( "1234" ); 
                                      ^ 

Sketch uses 11,850 bytes (4%) of program storage space. Maximum is 253,952 bytes. Global variables use 1,022 bytes (12%) of dynamic memory, leaving 7,170 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 8,192 bytes.
```

From "sketch" on isn't an error message, its build status.

Let's break that down.

```
file name:line number:character on that line:type of error: error description 
problem line
^ marking where on the above line the compiler thinks the problem is
```

File name: C:\Users\mwhit_000\Desktop\Capstone\Security_System\Security_System2\Security_Sy‌​stem2.ino

Line number: 27

Column: 38

Type of error: Warning

Description: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

Error line: `Password password = Password( "1234" );`

So this is quite literally telling you you are converting a constant string into a non-constant string right the freak here: `Password password = Password( "1234" );`

Why is this bad? "1234" is a constant string. the "1234" cannot be changed. Password takes a non-constant string and makes no promises that it won't try to change the string's value. If Password tries to change "1234" into something else, the results are undefined. The program may crash. It could keep running and crash later. It could eat a cat.